# When $x\to 0$, what is the order of $(x^2+x^{\frac13})^{\frac15}-(x^2+x^{\frac15})^{\frac13}?$

Tags: calculus

When $x\to 0$, what is the order of $$(x^2+x^{\frac13})^{\frac15}-(x^2+x^{\frac15})^{\frac13}?$$

Comment: Wouldn't that be like $\;0-0=0\;$ in the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
(x^2+x^{\frac13})^{\frac15}-(x^2+x^{\frac15})^{\frac13}&=x^{\frac1{15}}\left[(1+x^{\frac53})^{\frac15}-(1+x^{\frac95})^{\frac15}\right]\\
&=x^{\frac1{15}}\left[(1+\frac15x^{\frac53}+o(x^2))-(1+\frac13x^{\frac95}+o(x^2))\right]\\
&=\frac15x^{\frac{26}{15}}+o(x^{\frac{26}{15}}).
\end{align}$$